# jekyll - plugins support - how does it work?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I've just found [this comment](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/issue/19#issue/19/comment/280708) from mojombo:

> The latest on master now has Plugin support. Look at lib/jekyll/converters for examples of how they're done. Also, any *.rb files in a _plugins directory will be loaded so that you can create custom plugins of your own.

I've had a look [/lib/jekyll/converters](http://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/tree/ace99110012a7e0d4a18cf7b7a7e5e6d0201a50f/lib/jekyll/converters) but could not understand how they were supposed to work.

Can anyone explain this to me ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A new plugins wiki page has been created. It explains everything I needed to know about jekyll plugins:

http://wiki.github.com/mojombo/jekyll/plugins

Closing this question!